# Should I add pollution to my worldbuilding even though it's not part of the main story

Tags: environment

So the world I'm writing is a multi-polar world where every nation has their own battleships and aircrafts. And aerial warfare is kind of normal (like Ace Combat). But as I progress with my idea, I've realized that the constant use of aircrafts could lead to air pollution which I'm not a fan but don't know hot to tackle. Should I avoid mentioning this kind of topic to my story?

Comment: This seems much more of a writing-choice question than a worldbuilding one. You could take a look at our [writing.se] stack, take their tour, read-up in their help centre etc. then see if your post can be adapted to fit there.

Comment: What us aerial warfare like Ace Combat?

Comment: AlexP - Ace, Ace II and Ace of Aces are plane dogfight games. Played them as kid in early '90. Was some kind of society realted to this games and some films like Top Gun.

Comment: You need a lot more military aircraft to noticeably increase pollution over what we have today. I would be more concerned about massive fires caused by constant warfare.

Comment: Do you address bathroom breaks for pilots?

Answer (score 5):

### Good worldbuilding doesn't mean "absolute-realism"

There's often a misconception people have when trying to make something artistically "good" : Thinking they need to be realistic at all costs.

But look at the best animations movies in the world, according to the [12 principles of animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDqjIdI4bF4), characters should squish and squash themselves much further than reality to be easily understandable and entertaining. In video games, no-one cares that you didn't blow yourself up when you make a [rocket-jump](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viqqbmLBbV4). And in movies, we never see how people manage to get past the costs of rebuilding the skyscrapers in just a few months.

What's the common point in all these? They're following their intentions. If your intentions is to have a blast<sup>1</sup>, then yes, jumping with a rocket-launcher seems very fun and you should do it! If the point is to be understandable and give clear personality traits to characters, then squash the hell out of them! And if your movie is about giving a christian [aura to yo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman)[ur super-heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Batman_(film)) or you just need to ride [to the next epic battle (or joke)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-Punch_Man), then why have people grumble about how hard it will be to rebuild the city?

Bringing realism is one possible intention, but it's certainly not an absolute necessity to follow. If your goal is to talk about bromance in the sky, or I don't know how bad the enemy and their ideology are during dogfights, then it's not useful to talk about global warming or pollution. It'll only dilute what you want to tell in your world later on, because it's exactly like story plots and characters : Every world element you add or detail gives the color and melody of your work, and that's what matters.

### Conclusion?

Now it's up to you to decide if bringing pollution is an important topic you want to talk about. If the dark, pessimistic tint it usually gives in the background will help you portray what you want to tell. Or if what you actually need is only some self-consistency and nothing in "pollution" or "global-warming" appeals to you, then just throw this concept in the bins of untold topics. Almost nobody looks in the bin of untold topics.

---

<sup>1: (pun intended :p)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Does it serve some purpose in your story?

World building is done to tell a story a story all elements of word building should somehow relate to that story. This doesn't mean that every point of world building must be somehow connected to the main plot.  World building can service the story in other ways. Adding small or unrelated details for example can increase immersion and suspension of diselief. It can also add context to characters and character decisions, understanding that culture and worldview of one of your character comes from may help the reader better understand their decisions going forward.

Ask yourself if the story would be weakened in any way if this point a world building was taken out? If the answer is no then yes you should probably take it out.

Answer (score 3):

### Could it change the plot?

The point where violations of suspension of disbelief really stand out in peoples minds is when they can picture the plot unfolding very differently IF the theoretical part of your setting is changed.  So, if the detail is so small as maybe causing increased lung cancer by 3% in the general populous, then it's not important.  Even if someone thinks, "that air must be bad to breath", their mind will quickly move on to the next part of the story.

However, if the amount of pollution is so bad that people should be dying off in droves: then when a viewer sees countless people going about their daily lives, it will interfere with their focus on the story as they question how those people are able to get by without respirators on.

### Could it make the setting more interesting or unique?

The more important question in this case is not do you need to include it so much as what you could add to your setting by including it. When I have a thought like this, I always try to picture the worst case scenarios.  Acid rain, a constant thick smog covering everything, extreme global warming, people needing to put on hazmat suits just to leave their home, etc.  While this may not immediately be the story you want to tell, it is worth exploring the possibilities because you might stumble across plot hooks far more interesting than you had in mind.